# Cucumber sending string list as parameter

Tags: java, cucumber

I am using cucumber 4.3.0 and I would like to send an ArrayList of String in one of my sentences. It would give something like that:

```
Given I am on page <page>
When I do stuff
Then keywords "toto, tata, titi" are here
```

So far, I have thought of splitting the String "toto, tata, titi" into an Array (using "," as separator) however, I'm wondering if there are any cleaner solution?

I have tried doing this:

```
Given I am on page <page>
When I do stuff
Then the following keywords are here: toto, tata, titi
```

With

```
@Then("^the following keywords are here: (.*)$")
public void theFollowingKeywordsAreHere(List<String> datas) {
     //some code
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Could not convert arguments for step ...
...
Caused by: io.cucumber.cucumberexpressions.CucumberExpressionException: ParameterType {anonymous} failed to transform [toto, tata, titi, tutu] to java.util.List<java.lang.String>
```

---

So, any idea on how to make that work without using the string split solution?

Comment: Is this answer helpful ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37820840/pass-array-value-in-cucumber-feature-file
Or this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45033860/how-to-pass-list-of-strings-from-cucumber-scenario

Comment: @SlightlyKosumi [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53445978/10512595) is what I'm looking for, but I wasn't able to make it work (it gives me the "Could not convert arguments" error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it works only with `DataTable`.  Like this:

```
@Then("following keywords are here")
public void theFollowingKeywordsAreHere(DataTable data) {
        List<List<String>> dataList = data.asLists(String.class);
        String data1 = dataList.get(0).get(0);
        String data2 = dataList.get(0).get(1);
        String data3 = dataList.get(0).get(2);
```

Answer (score 6):

The only way to get a `List` from the `Gherkin` input is to use [datatables](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/tree/master/datatable).

To use this approach in your example you would have to re-implement the `Then` step, like this:

```
...
Then following keywords are here
| toto | tata | titi |
```

With mapping step like this (notice there is no regular expression to match any keywords, just the step itself):

```
@Then("^following keywords are here$")
public void theFollowingKeywordsAreHere(List<String> data) {
 //some code
}
```

This would normally accept `DataTable`, but `List<String>` will also work as cucumber can convert it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following :

```
Then following keywords are here
| toto | tata | titi |


@Then("following keywords are here")

public void theFollowingKeywordsAreHere(List data) {

//some code

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this layout in the feature file

```
Then the following keywords are here
| toto | 
| tata | 
| titi |
```

Then you should then be able to use this step method...

```
@Then("^the following keywords are here$")
public void theFollowingKeywordsAreHere(List<String> datas) {
     //some code
}
```